# How to deal with manager who has no expertise and doesn't listen to advice?

Tags: manager

I was hired as a subject matter expert in analytics. However was assigned a manager without any experience in the field. The problem is I've been repeatedly telling him projects should be discovered from end users. He disagrees and comes up with ideas himself. Consequently, projects the team produces don't end up being used.

Does anyone have any experience in a similar situation with a manager who doesn't listen to advice? How were you able to persuade them?

Comment: Join the club - I think we've all been there

Comment: Who does your manager report to? Is there a client? another team? or some sort of stackholder? If they aren't pushing new ideas, there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does anyone have any experience in a similar situation with a manager who doesn't listen to advice?

Yes, lived through three years of it after a great manager left.

> How were you able to persuade them?

I wasn't.  I don't work there now.

Do you best to fix it, but keep your ears open for a new opportunity.

---

Things I tried that might work for you:

- Keep careful track of items requested
- Get a solid plan in your evaluation which specifies what the manager is responsible for
- Politic around the office to find out what *actually* needs to be done and what others *want* done.
- Pitch those products to manager
- Scream loudly in the car ride home when they are all rejected.
- Leave enough time and re-pitch the ideas as though the manager thought of them
- Set a time limit on how long you should put into this job unless it changes

Answer (score 10):

Get everything in writing
Send him suggestions, advice and ideas in writing, if he rejects them, politely ask him the reason and have it in writing.

The next project, when same situation happens, you can refer him to the emails

People tend to have short and selective memories, emails don't

Comment: Great first answer (beat me to it :-) Another aspect of getting it in writing is that sooner or later someone higher up is going to notice what can happen, and, human nature being what it is, your manager is unlikely to accept the blame. If they should then happen to pint the finger at you, you want to be in a position to point it right back where it belongs.

Comment: I had issues with an arrogant manager in the past who lacked technical expertise. I ensured that I documented everything I did, and that all tasks were requested and tracked via email. This, combined with a professional attitude ensured his failures did not tarnish my reputation. Eventually his managers would bypass him and engage directly with me, which was much more productive for all involved.

Comment: People who are corrected **should** appreciate your honesty. And *(humor intended)* they should be glad that you **made the effort to collect evidence** that **documents their failures**. Humor aside, and to be clear: I do like the answer (no downvote!) but *just a warning* think through how (and if) you should present it to boss. How your boss sees things matters. Think about that before presenting the evidence to the boss. Remember that OP describes a person who is already a bad boss, who doesn't listen, doesn't take advice from OP, etc. Again... YES always collect it in case you need it!

Answer (score 0):

Be more assertive in your talk to him. Don't let him walk over you instead you take the charge and show him facts.